# Как через сущность bot получить доступ к state в aiogram?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

У меня в боте происходит сбор данных про букинг компьютера, там какой клуб компьютер время и тд. Потом бот получает из сервера ссылку на оплату, чтобы пользователь оплатил. Потом в сервер мне должен прийти callback от системы платежей. И потом мне как то нужно вызвать hendler бота из сервера, чтобы он отправил сообщение пользователю что оплата прошла успешно, и потом в боте мне нужно достать данные из state, который я использовал для сбора данных о букинге, чтобы отправить запрос на сервер с этими данными. Как я понял хендлер я никак вызвать из вне не могу, поэтому я пришел к выводу чтобы использовать webhook, чтобы потом просто дергать его из сервера. Вопрос остался только в том как мне получить доступ к данным state, который я использовал для сбора данных имея только сущность bot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно вот так сделать.

```py
from aiogram import Dispatcher
state = Dispatcher.get_current().current_state()
```

Comment: Такой вопрос еще возник эти state же для каждого пользователя свои будут или как?

Comment: Ну да. При каждом срабатывании хендлера стейт будет принадележать тому юзеру который написал или сделал колбек.

Comment: Посмотрел какие значение он требует, там написано chat и user. Это id чата и id user нужно передавать? Или можно только id чата передать?

Comment: Если юзер в ЛС с ботом тогда в чат айди и юзер айди пишется юзер айди.